# Hamiltonian of a quantum field theory

Tags: quantum-field-theory, operators, hamiltonian

I am reading through Srednicki's Quantum Field Theory book ([https://web.physics.ucsb.edu/~mark/qft.html](https://web.physics.ucsb.edu/%7Emark/qft.html)).

On page 26, Equation 1.30, Srenicki writes the Schrödinger equation for $n$ number of particles in a potential $U(\mathbf{x}_j)$ with a particle-particle interaction term $V(\mathbf{x}_j - \mathbf{x}_k)$.

He then writes an equation on page 27 [Equation (1.32)], which he states is the Hamiltonian of a quantum field theory.

Where does this Hamiltonian come from?

[[This question sheds some light on the matter](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/70377). However, I do not understand the order of the $a$ and $a^{\dagger}$, does $\mathbf{E}$ commute with $a^{\dagger}$?]

Comment: Looks like the $E$ in that other Physics.SE post is the energy, which is just a number. Not sure why they put it in bold. It may also help to write out the equations you're referencing for those who don't have immediate access to the text (or don't want to go searching).

Comment: I'm guessing, but I think the question is "How do we go from position space Schrödinger equation to the hamiltonian written in terms of creation & annihilation operators?"

Comment: I suggest the author check out any of many different condensed matter many-body physics books. An accessible introduction would be chapter 2 of [Altland/Simons](https://www.amazon.com/Condensed-Matter-Theory-Alexander-Altland/dp/0521769752), or an extremely careful and complete exposition can be found in chapter 1 of [Negele/Orland](https://www.amazon.com/Quantum-Many-particle-Systems-Frontiers-Physics-ebook/dp/B07B8FBX2X/ref=sr_1_1?dchild=1&keywords=negele+orland&qid=1616563717&s=books&sr=1-1).

Comment: @RichardMyers If $E$ is just a number then I guess you could swap $a^{\dagger}$ with $E$, then $E$ is replaced with the Hamiltonian of the time-independent Schrödinger equation for multiple particles?

Comment: @NahPlsMan What they have written is already the Hamiltonian. All that form is saying is that $a^\dagger a$ is the number operator for some particle. If each particle has energy $E$, then a state of $N$ such particles (assuming no interactions) will have energy $EN$. That is all. Note, however, that they are suppressing a lot of information in their notation, so what they're written is really just schematic.

Comment: @RichardMyers My mistake, I meant to say the Hamiltonian of a single particle. I see, thanks.